# Acumatica, Error #115 nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm working in Acumatica version 5.00.2749.

I have an Acumatica DAC that will not let me insert a new record for fields defined as `PXDBQuantity` or `PXDBDecimal`; they must be commented out of the DAC for the record to be inserted.

This is from the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
    [Qty] [float] NULL
```

But it generates the same error even whether or not a default value is provided using either of the methods below.

```
    [Qty] [float] NULL DEFAULT 0.0
```

or

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.ImportTranDetail
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_ImportTranDetail_Qty] DEFAULT ((0.0))
    FOR [Qty]
```

The fragment below is from the DAC.

```
#region Qty
public abstract class qty : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected Decimal? _Qty;

[PXDBQuantity()]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Quantity", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
public virtual Decimal? Qty
{
  get
  {
    return this._Qty;
  }
  set
  {
    this._Qty = value;
  }
}
#endregion
```

Here's the code fragment that inserts the record; please note the `HasValue` always equals `true` when executing code and the exception is never thrown.

```
  ImportTranDetail lookupTranDetail = new ImportTranDetail();
  ...

  lookupTranDetail.Qty = 1; // also tried Convert.ToDecimal(1)

  if (lookupTranDetail.Qty.HasValue == false)
  {
    // this is never executed
    throw new PXException("Oops, Qty doesn't have a value again!");
  }

  // Consistently getting this error when trying to insert a new record
  // Error #115: An error occurred while processing the field Qty : Nullable object must have a value
  try
  {
    Details.Cache.Insert(lookupTranDetail);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new PXException(ex.Message);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the columns were not properly defined in relation to the DAC.

Qty was `FLOAT` and changed to `DECIMAL(25,6)`
Amt was `FLOAT` and changed to `DECIMAL(19,4)`